# How to do these drawings?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I was reading a [paper](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~jucurry/papers/sca.pdf) online when I saw some beautiful pictures. I wonder if it is done with tikz or if it is even LaTeX. What do you think? How can I do things of this sort?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can it be done with TikZ? Yes, I'd say so. Mostly just some filled ellipses with reduced opacity. Was it done with TikZ? Impossible to say for certain, ask the author. My guess would be no.

Comment: I think I'm going to add another image, to see if it helps. Anyway i'll try to contact the author.

Comment: There is a huge gallery of examples on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) – see for example [Venn diagramm | TikZ example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/) which also uses transparency and overlapping circles.

Comment: Looks like MS Visio to me

Comment: @percusse for this kind of pictures do you think that MS Visio is the best option? Is Tikz a lot of work to get simple results? I'd love to add stuff like this to a project I'm doing but I don't know what to do.

Comment: If you are going to use them many times you can spare time with TikZ but otherwise whatever works for you is the best option.

Comment: @Abellan, Tikz is a long learning process however it generates extremely high quality pictures.